# Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox input is not visible

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms, telerik

Following the tutorials for RadAutoCompleteBox control for ASP WebForms, I have the following code:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox SelectMethod="GetUserTags"
                            runat="server" 
                            ID="tagsAutoCompleteBox" 
                            InputType="Token" 
                            Skin="Metro"
                            DataValueField="Id" 
                            DataTextField="Value" 
                            Width="200px" 
                            DropDownWidth="200px">
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

However I can't add any tags, because input is not accessible (clicking in control does nothing). After investigating generated HTML, I see, that inner input has set `max-width: 0` in its style.

[image]

When I manually delete this style entry in chrome developer tools, it works as expected. Data source is correctly set, entries can be added and read. The only problem then is, that tags are above the input, not on the left:

[image]

How to work around this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Telerik controls and if not - have you tried it? Remove bits and pieces to see whether something simple fixes the issues. Try adding Width. Open a support ticket with Telerik.

Comment: I was having some strange display issues with the `RadAutoCompleteBox` as well in IE11. I switched the render mode by adding this tag which worked: `RenderMode="Lightweight"`. Let me know if this works for you and I'll post it as a workaround.

Comment: I don't think we'll be investigating it further, as we are deprecating our ASP Web Form application in favor of MVC-Angular one. However feel free to post it, if it helped in your case. Personally i think this is a matter of Telerik library version, as it was mentioned before.